# Fragmenttransition replace doesn't clean button

Tags: android, fragmenttransaction

I'm trying to do a Navigation Drawer with a toolbar with two buttons. When I click the buttons it should switch between two fragments.

```
switch (v.getId()) {
        case R.id.lay_publist_toolbar:
                android.support.v4.app.Fragment listFrag=  new PubListFragment();
                FragmentManager listfragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
                FragmentTransaction listfragmentTransaction = listfragmentManager.beginTransaction();
            listfragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.lay_hole_fragment, listFrag,"i")
                        .addToBackStack(null)
                        .commit();
            break;
        case R.id.lay_maplist_toolbar:
            android.support.v4.app.Fragment nextFrag=  new MapsActivity();
            FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
            FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
            fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.lay_hole_fragment, nextFrag,"d")
                    .addToBackStack(null)
                    .commit();
            break;
```

The xml of the mainactivity

```
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:elevation="7dp">

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <include
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        layout="@layout/toolbar">
    </include>
<FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/lay_hole_fragment"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Solo"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal|top" />

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@drawable/common_google_signin_btn_icon_light_normal"
        android:layout_gravity="center" />

    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Click here"
        android:layout_gravity="left|center_vertical" />
</FrameLayout>
...
```

In the first case nothing inside the Frameayout is cleaned. In the second case, the fragment implements a Google Maps, and everything inside the FrameLayout is cleaned, except the Button. I know I could change visibility of the button.
Any help about why this behaviour?

Answer (score 0):

I think you must use

```
fragmentManager.beginTransaction().replace();
```

instead of

```
fragmentManager.beginTransaction().add();
```

Comment: It doesn't solve the problem of the button. But actually is better for switch between both fragments, thanks